# Ошибка SQLiteException: no such table в Android P

Tags: android, sqlite

На Android P выдает ошибку, при попытке запустить приложение

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bluda (code 1
>   SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bluda WHERE categoryID
>   = 1

Это ошибка в Android P или  как ее решить подскажите пожалуйста.. Вот мой класс, где указывается путь к БД, сама БД и запросы

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kitchen.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getBluda(long categoryID) {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_BLUDA, null, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = "
                + categoryID, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // база не существует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке, нету таблицы bluda. Точно создается эта таблица?

Comment: Да, конечно. Бд уже готовая с данными. До android 9 все работает без ошибок

Answer (score 2):

[тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53572375/8211160) был хороший ответ на вопрос как работать с базой из ресурсов 
Позже для этого я начал использовать библиотеку `SqliteAssetHelper`. Все то же самое только кода меньше писать.

Сама же ошибка, возникает потому что База создана ,как вы уже поняли, а таблицы нету. Скорее всего она возникла после того , как вы добавили или заменили базу новым исправленым файлом.
Попробуйте через андроид студио, при подключеном девайсе очистить папку с базой данных.
Она находится в папке data/data/ имя пакета/database 
Но для начала можете просто выгрузить этот файл и почитать для интереса.
При такой ошибке я открывал базу из этой папки и в ней действительно не было таблиц. Хотя я создавал и переустанавливал как казалось. И проходил тот же путь что и вы. Поэтому просто все удалял оттуда и переустанавливал приложение. Тогда все начинало работать. Но
Это неудобно делать при обновлении поэтому в ссылке есть ответ как решается данная проблема.

Но она решается еще проще при использовании `SqliteAssetHelper`. 
Там просто вызывается метод `setForceUpgrade()` при выбросе исключения

Comment: Я посмотрю вашу ссылку спасибо. Но я приложение удалял даже и даже на новое виртуальное устройство устанавливал ошибка все равно есть.

Comment: Попробуйте удалить не приложение а именно базу данных из папки приложения. И потом загрузить туда новую через менеджер в андроид студио.

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать как доберусь до компа.

Comment: Если коротко Ваш код создания базы данных и чтения не совсем такой каким должен быть. Нужно чуть чуть передклать

Comment: А какой должен быть? Есть пример когда бд уже готовая используется?

Comment: Я привел пример, он доступен по ссылке с пояснениями